# 'Invalid account name or access token' when deploying to Thegraph

Tags: blockchain, bsc, ipfs, typescript, graphs

I'm currently working on deploy a subgraph to the hosted service on thegraph. It's to track volume and liquidity of a new token on the bsc.

The thing is, I'm using a v1 clone from PCS, and everything seems to work, but when I try to deploy (into my thegraph account) I get:

```
✖ Failed to deploy to Graph node https://api.thegraph.com/deploy/: Invalid account name or access token
```

I already did:

```
graph auth https://api.thegraph.com/deploy/ '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
```

And everything necessary, but still not working. The subgraph repo is public and you can see it in:

https://github.com/topospec/gol-subgraph

What can be happening? Everything compiles, and build. The problem is with credentials.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

This happens if the access token is not set as the deployment key properly. Try running the command: **graph auth --product hosted-service**

You should get the below message if successfull
[image]

Comment: Is deploy key the same as access token?

Comment: Yes, the very same

Answer (score 0):

the account name is your github username. init the project again with: githubusername/projectname